# What is the difference in having a space in between px?

Tags: css

What is the difference between:

```
border-right: 1px dotted #CCCCCC;
```

and:

```
border-right: 1 px dotted #CCCCCC;
```

Is there any?

Is the second incorrect? Do you need to have the number right next to `px`?

Comment: Surely a few minutes of fiddling could have answered this for you... http://jsbin.com/uremab/1/edit

Comment: If you go to that link in firefox and chrome, the results differ.

Comment: Interesting, but if it always works one way, and only sometimes works the other way, which should you choose? ;)

Comment: @AlexWayne I get where you're coming from, but that's not a very practical approach to programming. Would you suggest as much for a beginner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [CSS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#length-units):

> The format of a length value (denoted by `<length>` in this
>   specification) is a `<number>` (with or without a decimal point)
>   immediately followed by a unit identifier (e.g., px, em, etc.). After
>   a zero length, the unit identifier is optional.

So, immediately after the number should come the unit identifier.  It's likely that different browsers will enforce this differently, but when in doubt, go with what's in the spec.

Cheers

Comment: @Phrogz Thanks for the edit, didn't notice those got dropped. +1 for being a good sport too.  :)

Answer (score 6):

> *"The format of a length value (denoted by `<length>` in this specification) is a `<number>` (with or without a decimal point) **immediately followed by a unit identifier** (e.g., px, em, etc.). After a zero length, the unit identifier is optional."*

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#length-units

In other words: having a space before the "px" is a syntactical mistake. Have you [validated your CSS](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there was a CSS validator

Answer (score 2):

border-right: 1px dotted #CCCCCC; is correct

border-right: 1 px dotted #CCCCCC; is incorrect

This is because there are multiple ways to define the length like "1px" or "1" but the problem is when you seperate them by a space like "1 px" css would think the width is "1" and the next classifier is "px". By that I mean in the incorrect example the css thinks "px" is what you are trying to enter instead of "dotted". And so forth for the rest of the code. The problem is though that in the incorrect example you have too many selectors so the code gets confused and won't work.

Comment: frankly, to make code not confused here is not that really hard, and as for me adding blank makes CSS better readable. OTOH the rules are the rules, good or bad

Answer (score 1):

I am working wordpress and had a media query not work. It was just ignored completely. Took a frustrating hour to realize this was the issue. I had a space before the px (example: "648 px" instead of "648px").

I would suggest not leaving in a space between even though most of the time it works fine.